# make swift class be available to my objc class for same project during setuping podspec for my repo

Tags: swift, podspec

I setup a podspec for my repo (framework). In my repo, there are some swift classes, I would like these swift classes be availble to some objC classes in the same repo.
I know xcode will automatically generate a header file: `product-Swift.h` file, so that object-c class can use swift classes by importing this header file.
my question is that 
how do I setup podspec file so that this swift header file can be generated and objC class can import it ?

in my podspec file, I enable module definition and generate interface build header file for swift. but I can not get my objC class compiled since the product-Swift.h file can not be found.

```
 s.xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE ' => 'YES', 'SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME' => 'Product-Swift.h' }
```

any ideas are welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u get this resolved. I am in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding *@obcj* prefix to you class name. btw, you'll have to re-build your project before objective c will know the class

```
@objc class myClass{
     //this class will be available in Objective c
}
```

Comment: Hi. By doing this the Swift.h file is created, but i dont see any swift file is being included though.